# Laravel migration from nullable to not null with null data in database

Tags: laravel, migration, nullable

my code below is working fine. Problem is when i got data in database which is null in user_id field. Migration rollback will not pass successfully. What is good approach to solve this problem?
Should i change every null in column user_id to empty string before i change nullable to false in rollback?

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('user_id')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
    
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('user_id')->nullable(false)->change();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been seem before, I couldn't find other solution than update the values to empty string before changing the column, the database engine will always complaint.

---

Updated:

You could do this like this and should work:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

/*
*
* Some code
*
*/


public function up()
{
    DB::table('classes')->whereNull('user_id')->update(['user_id'=>'']);
    Schema::table('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('user_id')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

Comment: okay, thank you so much for your answer. DB::statement(raw_sql) is good solution or maybe you have better for this situation?

Comment: Yes you could do that, just updated my answer.

Comment: thank you so much , your solution is better than just raw sql